# Dump debug_loc section from executable

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, dwarf

How do I dump debug_loc section from an executable on Linux if default options (-g) are provided to GCC while compiling a C file? I use `readelf` linux utility.

GCC by default produces DWARF info in DWARF4 format, so if I pass -g-dwarf2 I can see .debug_loc section but how do inspect that section if info is generated with default options as I don't see the section in dump?

Comment: Do you use a recent version of binutils? On Ubuntu 14.04 I can build executable with "gcc -g test.c -o test". Then do "readelf --debug-dump=info test" and see it's DWARF 4, then do readelf --debug-dump=decodedline test and get the contents of .debug_line section.

Comment: ohh I did not know this option. Please explain more about this and put it in answer I will accept it thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use a recent version of binutils? On Ubuntu 14.04 I can build executable with "gcc -g test.c -o test".

With "readelf --debug-dump=info test" I can confirm it's using DWARF 4.

After that, you have (at least) two ways to dump the contents of .debug_line section.

> readelf --debug-dump=decodedline test

This will dump decoded line number information. You get line==address mappings directly.

There is also:

> readelf --debug-dump=rawline test

This gets you raw debug_line contents.

Comment: Wait a sec. This is giving me contents of debug_line section and not debug_loc? what is the connection/difference?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I thought you were looking for debug_line section. Use --debug-dump=loc to get .debug_loc.

Comment: FYI: for simple executable (one function) this generates no debug_loc section for some reason. For more complex one, it does. Funny.

Comment: I don't see .debug_loc in dwarf 4 (I can find it in dwarf 2, same code). Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, .debug_loc is generated for optimized code. Try optimizing your code using compiler flags.